# How to access an nsarray count in a special case

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have block set up as follows:

```
    id block = ^(id obj, BOOL *ignored) 
{
  id data = [self.writer dataWithObject:obj];
  NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];          
};
```

When i do the call:

```
[[obj objectForKey:@"roster] objectForKey:@"players"];
```

I am looking at an array of players. When I add .count, it cannot find a count because it says count is not a property of id. How can I access the count of this array?

Edit:

This is my full block:

```
id block = ^(id obj, BOOL *ignored) {
                 id data = [self.writer dataWithObject:obj];

                 NSMutableArray *players = (NSMutableArray*)[[obj objectForKey:@"roster"] objectForKey:@"players"];
                 _players = [NSMutableArray array];

                 //Create player objects then add them to the array.

                 for (int i = 0; i <= players.count; i++)
                 {
                     [_players addObject:[HNPlayerObject newPlayerWithPlayerId:(@"%@",[[[obj objectForKey:@"roster"] objectForKey:@"players"][i] objectForKey:@"id"])FirstName:(@"%@",[[[obj objectForKey:@"roster"] objectForKey:@"players"][i] objectForKey:@"first"]) LastName:(@"%@",[[[obj objectForKey:@"roster"] objectForKey:@"players"][i] objectForKey:@"last"]) Number:[(@"%@",[[[obj objectForKey:@"roster"] objectForKey:@"players"][i] objectForKey:@"number"]) intValue] Team:@"Badgers" Position:@"Unknown" Description:@"" GamesPlayed:[(@"%@",[[[obj objectForKey:@"roster"] objectForKey:@"players"][i] objectForKey:@"gp"]) intValue] Goals:[(@"%@",[[[obj objectForKey:@"roster"] objectForKey:@"players"][i] objectForKey:@"g"]) intValue] Assists:[(@"%@",[[[obj objectForKey:@"roster"] objectForKey:@"players"][i] objectForKey:@"a"]) intValue] Points:[(@"%@",[[[obj objectForKey:@"roster"] objectForKey:@"players"][i] objectForKey:@"pts"]) intValue] PenaltyMinutes:[(@"%@",[[[obj objectForKey:@"roster"] objectForKey:@"players"][i] objectForKey:@"pim"]) intValue] PlusMinus:[(@"%@",[[[obj objectForKey:@"roster"] objectForKey:@"players"][i] objectForKey:@"pm"]) intValue] IsPlaying:NO]];
                     [_playersTableView reloadData];
                 }

                 [_playersTableView reloadData];
             };
```

I am getting this error: 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 17 beyond bounds [0 .. 16]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NSArray *array = (NSArray*)[[obj objectForKey:@"roster] objectForKey:@"players"];
```

Then you'll able to access the count property.

Comment: I am having another problem that you might be able to help with.

Comment: Share it with me so I can know if I can do it.